# Deprecation notice when using in_memory security user

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.3, symfony-security

Running Symfony 3.3.15 I'm currently having some issues with the autowiring mechanism.

The following deprecation warning is showing up 3 times in my log:

> Autowiring services based on the types they implement is deprecated since Symfony 3.3 and won't be supported in version 4.0. You should rename (or alias) the "security.user.provider.concrete.in_memory_info@website.xyz" service to "Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface" instead.

The only place I can imagine this error occurs is my `security.yml` since I've defined the user there.

This file has the following content:

```
security:
    encoders:
        My\Bundle\CompanyBundle\Entity\Contact:
            algorithm: bcrypt
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt

    providers:
        chain_provider:
            chain:
                providers: [in_memory, contact_provider]
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    info@website.xys:
                        password: "some encrypted password"
                        roles: ["ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN"]
        contact_provider:
            entity:
                class: MyCompanyBundle:Contact
                property: emailAddress

        api_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: ApiBundle:ApiUser
                property: apiKey
    firewalls:
        # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        api:
            pattern: ^/
            stateless: true
            provider: api_user_provider
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - App\Component\Security\TokenAuthenticator
        main:
            anonymous: ~
            provider: chain_provider
            form_login:
                username_parameter:  login[username]
                password_parameter:  login[password]
                csrf_parameter: login[_token]
                login_path: login
                check_path: login
            logout:
                path:   /logout
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
```

Even if I only specify the in_memory provider in this file, the warning keeps popping up.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appeared to be a bug, users were registered as services.

A fix was made from Symfony 2.7 upwards: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/25837